# Are on/off switches for a 12 volt kids ride on tractor interchangeable?

Tags: voltage, power

I don't have much knowledge when it comes to electrical stuff so, I could really use some help. I got my son a 12 volt ride on tractor several weeks ago. The red LED power on/off switch is now broken. The switch has 3 prongs on it and says 10A 250VAC on it.  I bought a new switch that looks very similar but instead it says 25A 12V on it. It was the only switch I could find after stoping at several parts stores. I don't want to hook it up if it's going to mess up the functionality of the entire tractor. So my question is; can I use a 25A 12V switch  to replace the 10A 250VAC switch that originally came on the tractor? If the answer is no, I cannot use the 25A 12V switch, does anyone have any suggestions on how I could fix the original broken switch? It used to click when I'd turn it on but now it does not. The red button just kind of wiggles around instead of it clicking on/off. I'm unclear why or how it broke but once I took the switch out, I noticed that one of the 3 prongs was missing, leaving a wire unplugged. Any advice or suggestions would be very helpful and appreciated since I have barely any knowledge in this subject. Thank you.

Comment: You say the original switch also has an LED and three prongs. How are the prongs labeled? Does the replacement switch have three prongs labeled the same as the original one? 

As far as the voltage/amperage ratings, you’re probably ok.

Answer (score 3):

The switch ratings are max.  As long as what you run through it is less than both 25A and less than 12V, you will be fine using that 25A 12V switch.

From the previous part, we know it is likely less than 10 A, 250VAC so you're good on amperage.  Verify that the voltage is less than 12 with a meter and install your part.

For installation, both are likely simple setups that connect one pin to one of the other two depending on the state of the switch.  Again, you can verify with meter before installing.

As for why the previous switch broke, theyre simple things that touch two pieces of metal together.  Some small plastic or metal part probably broke inside; it's usually more annoying to fix than replace.

Comment: The only thing I would add is that in some cases the DC ratings will differ from the AC ratings. For switches, this has to do with the fact that AC will naturally break any arcs every half cycle, but DC won't. But in this case, 12V is so much lower than 250V that it's unlikely to be an issue.